# Adding commas to a number

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to make a number like 1234567 go to be 1,234,567, but need some help. My thoughts were that I could use a split with `\d{3}` and then join a , to that. The problem with this though is that `\d{3}` groups it from the other end so it would be like 123,456,7 which I don't want.

Thanks lots for any help!

Comment: You may not be using Rails, but for anyone who is: `number_with_delimiter(1234567)`.

Comment: @MarkThomas The [source for `number_with_delimiter`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper/number_to_delimited_converter.rb) can be found on GitHub, in case you're a "learn by source" kind of person.

Comment: @user3606254 - Hopefully my answer shows a similar approach to what you were thinking!

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if ruby has already an option to format numbers but in regex you can do this

```
/\G([+-]?\d+?)(?=(?:\d{3})++(?=\.\d++$|$))/g
```

then replace with this

```
\1,
```

sample:
http://regex101.com/r/bA9cV2

Comment: Dumb question...why do you replace it with that instead of just ',' or something like that?

Comment: Couldnt understand what you meant

Comment: Full ruby example using this regex: `"1234567".gsub(/\G([+-]?\d+?)(?=(?:\d{3})++(?=\.\d++$|$))/, '\1,')`

Comment: To answer the OP's question, the replacement is each group of chars matched (`\1`) followed by a comma.

Comment: as @MarkThomas said, \1 is the match group, followed by a comma, so each 3 numbers, it add a comma to the match \1,

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Rails' ActiveSupport (even if I wasn't using Rails for the actual application), which also formats it properly for the current locale. If you aren't already using Rails, you'll need to install the gem:

```
gem install activesupport
```

Then, require it like this:

```
require "active_support/core_ext"
```

Then you can do:

```
=> ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(1234567)
=> "1,234,567"
```

Answer (score 0):

More precise code (handles integers only, as OP did not mention floats!):

```
def group_digits(n)
  n.to_s.chars
   .reverse
   .each_slice(3)
   .map(&:join)
   .join(",")
   .reverse
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
class Integer
  # To digit grouping                                                                                                                                                                        
  def to_dg
    x = self.to_s
    v = x[0]
    for i in 1...x.length
      v += "," if (x.length - i) % 3 == 0
      v += x[i]
    end

    v
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):016:0> 1234567.to_dg
=> "1,234,567"
```